# json string to parameters to POST

Tags: c#, post, json.net, deserialization, x-www-form-urlencoded

When I run this code, I get an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]'.
```

I am trying to pass this to a `POST` that takes parameters. Not sure how to do this?

```
using System.Dynamic; // ExpandObject
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

...

       var s = @"
        {
          ""time-in-force"": ""Day"",
          ""order-type"": ""Limit"",
          ""price"": ""2.0"",
          ""price-effect"": ""Credit"",
          ""legs"": [
             {
             ""instrument-type"": ""Equity Option"",
              ""symbol"": ""SPY   191018C00298000"",
              ""quantity"": 1,
              ""action"": ""Buy to Open""
             },
             {
             ""instrument-type"": ""Equity Option"",
              ""symbol"": ""SPY   191018C00295000"",
              ""quantity"": 1,
              ""action"": ""Sell to Open""
            }
          ]
        }
        ";

        try
        {
            dynamic json =
              JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(
                s,
                new ExpandoObjectConverter()
              );

            var iProps = json as IDictionary<string, Object>;
            var furl = new FormUrlEncodedContent((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)iProps);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

Comment: Do you certainlay need FormUrlEncodedContent? It would be much easier to use json application content. And it would be nice if you post an API header with input parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Code modifications Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aR8D.png)

Just use "GetEnumerator" to get iProps as IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
then you can iterate it and store it in List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>

Comment: I figured out what the problem is, and your code is correct. Thanks!